# how to store and retrieve video in database with C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, video, data-retrieval

I have a windows application with C# that I have the feature for user can add and retrieve video file in theirs data
how to store and retrieve video in database with C# winforms?
Is any way for this problem.
thank u for help.

Comment: Storing big files like video on database is not a good idea, store in db file names for recerence and the files in directories

Comment: videos are very small about 2 or 3 MB

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to store video in database. that will slowdown the process when you are trying to load video from database. instead of doing that you should store that video in your harddrive and store that file path only in your database. thus, you can stream your video quickly. BTW, if you want to store any file in the database than you can use `MemoryStream` or `FileStream` to read all bytes then you can write that bytes in database.

Try this code.

**NOTE: Following code is not compiled it may gives you error. This is just to get idea to know how to store video file in database.**

```
string path = @"D:\videos\myvideos.mpeg";

try
{
    using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fsSource.Length];
        int numBytesToRead = (int)fsSource.Length;
        int numBytesRead = 0;
        while (numBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead. 
            int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

            // Break when the end of the file is reached. 
            if (n == 0)
                break;

            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        }

        SqlCommand Cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
        Cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into MyTable(ID,Video,FileName,Format,Size)Values(@ID,@Video,@FileName,@Format,@Size)";
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Video", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "My File Name";
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "MPEG";
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bytes.length;
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: I don't have problem for insert. my problem is for retrieve when user wants to store file in specific path.

Comment: @Shell I'm not sure it's correct to say storing video in the DB is a bad idea. I know of at least three Enterprise Content Management Systems (eCMS) that store Video in the Database and cache it for Streaming. Vimeo use MySQL to store Video (http://davidwalsh.name/vimeo).